# How do I get the volume control button back for iPads and iPhones

Tags: iphone, wordpress, ipad

I am using the  wordpress player from the website on my computer and my iPhone and iPad.

Everything is going fine – Except the VOLUME CONTROL has disappeared when using on iPads and iPhones – it STILL APPEARS when playing from a computer.

How do I get the volume control button back for iPads and iPhones?